# break line of input text from a form in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input, angular6

i've designed a form that takes input text and stores it as string, problem is, if user hits "Enter" the text would not break line and instead would be displayed all together!
how should i fix this
i'm using angular6 framework with typscript, i was wondering if a pipe can solve this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.io.

Comment: Might as well skip stackblitz.io and just put the [mcve] here on Stack Overflow using Stack Snippets...

Answer (score 2):

You can't manage 'enter' keys in text boxes. To see the `enter` keys in your entered string you must use the `textarea`(you can style it like a textbox) like,

HTML:

```
<textarea type="text" #elem></textarea><br/>
<button (click)="checkValue()">Click to see the value</button>
<div *ngIf="value!=''">
    You have typed:<p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">{{value}}</p>
</div>
```

TS:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild("elem") inputChild: ElementRef;
  value='';
  checkValue(){
     this.value= this.inputChild.nativeElement.value;
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kg1gkf)

Update using `ngModel`

HTML:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="value" #elem></textarea><br/>
<div *ngIf="value!=''">
  You have typed:<p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">{{value}}</p>
</div>
```

TS:

```
export class AppComponent  {
   @ViewChild("elem") inputChild: ElementRef;
   name = 'Angular 6';
   value='';
}
```

[Updated Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h1czso)

Comment: Using Ngmodel will be easier then using inputChild
<textarea [(ngModel)]="val" type="text" #elem></textarea><br/>
and print the model value in html: {{val}}.

Comment: @T.Shashwat you are right, it is another way to do the same.

Comment: i am using ngModel, can u elaborate more on how i take the input of ngModel and format it as in your answer above?

Answer (score 1):

so, it seems there are many ways to do it, the one i chose is

> < p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">{{user.Diagnosis}}< /p>

all it seems to involve is some styling (white-space and pre-wrap)

thanks to all who helped especially `Rohan Kumar`